# upgrade TeeChart 2015 to TeeChart 2017 problems

Tags: delphi, teechart

I recently upgrade my TeeChart Pro 2015 to TeeChart Pro 2017.

But I found that most of chart file I saved by TeeChart 2015 are not able to be loaded by TeeChart 2017.

Exception throwed is  : Wrong *.tee file format.

Anyone can help me?

thanks.

Comment: Contact the vendor: https://www.steema.com/support_options

Comment: Hello,
Could you arrange a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because we can reproduce the problem? Also could you confirm which **TeecharFor.Net** are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Problem Solved.

It's not TeeChart problem.

I also upgrade Delphi from XE7 to XE10.2.

Write file functions must use TArray not point.